# Send different instances of Kafka Connect to different Kafka topic

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have tried to send the information of a Kafka Connnect instance in distributed mode with one worker to a specific topic, I have the topic name in the "archive.properties" file that use when I launch the instance.

But, when I send five or more instances, I see the messages merged in all topics.

The "solution" I thought was make a map to store the relation between ID and topic but it doesn't worked

Is there an specific Kafka connect implementation to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Hard to understand. Can try to show what you mean with an example? Also including code snippets is usually a good idea.

Comment: Can you post the code on how you create Kafka Connect?

Answer (score 1):

First, details on how you are running connect and which connector you are using will be very helpful.

Some connectors support sending data to more than one topic. For example, confluent-jdbc-sink will send each table to a separate topic. So this could be a limitation of the connector you are using.

Also depending on the connector and your use case - whether you need to run more than one connector. With the JDBC connector, you need one connector per database and it will handle all the tables. If you run two connectors on the same database and same tables, you'll get duplicates.

In short hopefully your connector has helpful documentation.

In the next release of Apache Kafka we are adding Single Message Transformations. One of the transformations can modify the target topic based on data in the event - so you can use the transformation to perform event routing.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer!
 We are trying to attack the problem from another angle in order to avoid this problem.